# Discord.js bot was working, added one extra command and everything broke. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord, discord.js

Tried to venture in to the realm of making discord bots. Followed along with a fairly simple tutorial, tweaking it along the way to fit what I was trying to make. The bot originally worked, but I went back in to add the "Mistake" command, and suddenly it's not working. I added in console.log pretty much everywhere, trying to figure out how far everything was getting.

When I start the bot, it will spit out the "Bot Online" log. When I input a command, it will spit out the "Commands" log, but it won't register the command at all. I've tried looking for any minor typos, missing brackets, etc... but I just can't seem to figure out what's gone wrong. I'm hoping that someone here can help! Thank you!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const SQLite = require('better-sqlite3');
const sql = new SQLite('./scores.sqlite');

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot Online');
  const table = sql.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'goals';").get();
  if (!table['count(*)']) {
    sql.prepare('CREATE TABLE goals (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, guild TEXT, goals INTEGER);').run();
    sql.prepare('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_goals_id ON goals (id);').run();
    sql.pragma('synchronous = 1');
    sql.pragma('journal_mode = wal');
  }

  //Statements to get and set the goal data
  client.getGoals = sql.prepare('SELECT * FROM goals WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?');
  client.setGoals = sql.prepare('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO goals (id, user, guild, goals) VALUES (@id, @user, @guild, @goals);');
});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  let goalTotal;
  if (message.guild) {
    goalTotal = client.getGoals.get(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
    if (!goalTotal) {
      goalTotal = {
        id: `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`,
        user: message.author.id,
        guild: message.guild.id,
        goals: 0,
      };
    }
  }

  if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  console.log('Commands');

  if (command === 'Goals') {
    console.log('Goals');
    return message.reply(`You Currently Have ${goalTotal.goals} Own Goals.`);
  }

  if (command === 'OwnGoal') {
    console.log('Own Goal');
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!user) return message.reply('You must mention someone.');
    let userscore = client.getGoals.get(user.id, message.guild.id);

    if (!userscore) {
      userscore = {
        id: `${message.guild.id}-${user.id}`,
        user: user.id,
        guild: message.guild.id,
        goals: 0,
      };
    }
    userscore.goals++;
    console.log({ userscore });
    client.setGoals.run(userscore);

    return message.channel.send(`${user.tag} has betrayed his team and now has a total of ${userscore.goals} own goals.`);
  }

  if (command === 'Mistake') {
    console.log('Mistake');
    const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
    if (!user) return message.reply('You must mention someone.');
    let userscore = client.getGoals.get(user.id, message.guild.id);

    if (!userscore) {
      return message.reply('This person has no Rocket Bot activity.');
    }
    if (userscore === 0) {
      return message.reply('This player currently has no goals.');
    }
    if (userscore > 0) {
      userscore.goals--;
    }
    console.log({ userscore });
    client.setGoals.run(userscore);

    return message.channel.send(`${user.tag} was falsely accused and now has a total of ${userscore.goals} own goals.`);
  }

  if (command === 'Leaderboard') {
    console.log('Leaderboard');
    const leaderboard = sql.prepare('SELECT * FROM goals WHERE guild = ? ORDER BY goals DESC;').all(message.guild.id);
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Rocket Bot Leaderboard')
      .setAuthor(client.user.username, client.user.avatarURL())
      .setDescription('Total Goals Scored Against Own Team:')
      .setFooter('Rocket Bot')
      .setThumbnail('https://imgur.com/a/S9HN4bT')
      .setColor('0099ff');

    for (const data of leaderboard) {
      embed.addFields({
        name: client.users.cache.get(data.user).tag,
        value: `${data.goals} goals`,
        inline: true,
      });
    }
    return message.channel.send({ embed });
  }

  if (command === 'RocketHelp') {
    console.log('Help');
    return message.reply(
      'Rocket Bot Commands:' +
        '\n' +
        '!Goals - See How Many Goals You Have Scored Against Your Own Team' +
        '\n' +
        '!OwnGoal - Tag Another Player With @ To Add One To Their Total' +
        '\n' +
        '!Mistake - Tag Another Player With @ To Subtract One From Their Total' +
        '\n' +
        '!Leaderboard - Show The Current Leaderboard'
    );
  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are improperly splitting the message content. You added `g` to the regex by accident.
Correct line:

```
const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

Because of improper args split, it could not find any command at all, hence no console log was invoked after `Commands`.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but I'm still having the same problem, it won't register any commands, yet it will still spit out the console.log('Commands') every time I try.

Comment: @KirkForADay ahhh, I see. your command is `const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();`, although you are comparing it with strings that have uppercase letters. Fix your if statements to be fully lowercase. Notify me if it helps.

Comment: That was entirely the problem. As always, something incredibly easy to overlook. I can't thank you enough - I've wasted so much time trying to figure out why this wasn't working.